# Como faço para entrar com diversos arquivos diferentes

Tags: c

Boa noite , estou com uma duvida, tenho um programa que vai receber diversos arquivos do tipo `nome.txt`, e devo contar quantos caracteres existem dentro do arquivo, tentei fazer um protótipo mas a duvida esta em como irei adicionar isso usando `getline` e usando ponteiros de arquivos??Ou seja, como recebo arquivos em txt e depois verifico os caracteres??

Segue abaixo o codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    int counter = 0;
    FILE* file = NULL;
    char * arquivo = NULL;
    char frases;
    size_t aux = 0;

    getline(&arquivo,&aux, stdin);

    file = fopen("arquivo", "r" );

    while(fgetc(file) != EOF)
        counter++;

    printf("%d", counter);

    fclose(file);

}
```

Comment: Não entendi bem a pergunta. O que está dando errado no seu programa? Qual era o resultado que você estava esperando?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> file = fopen("arquivo", "r" );
> ```

Esta instrução do teu programa vai abrir o ficheiro de nome `"arquivo"`; não vai abrir o ficheiro com o nome que o utilizador introduziu e que está contido na variável `arquivo`. Para isso precisas de fazer

```
file = fopen(arquivo, "r");
```

Além disso, segundo o [manual POSIX para `getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html), a vaiável contem o <kbd>ENTER</kbd> que o utilizador usou. Deves retirar esse <kbd>ENTER</kbd> antes de abrir o ficheiro.

Para fazeres com diversos ficheiros diferentes tens de fazer um ciclo. E colocar dentro desse ciclo o pedido de nome de ficheiro, a abertura de ficheiro, a contagem de caracteres, e o fecho do ficheiro.